# add properties in window.open for next page

Tags: javascript

I have two sites A and B in one domain.

Actually, I am in site A and wants to open site B per javascript:

```
window.open("B.html","...","Attributes");
```

Now, I want to use these Attributes to initalize the site A before "contentloaded". Is there a way to get these attributes after site B is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
// get these "Attributes" from transmitted window.open(..)
....
}
```

How does it work? Or is there a other (new) way to make it work? I dont want to use cookies or other html5-storages for that!

Comment: Would using the querystring be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'stateless' coms between web pages ( http ) is done via get, post, put, delete - GET looks the best here as @spassvogel says in the comment.

```
page2.html?param=paramvalue
```

the `window.open` method to 'pass values', can be done the same as

```
<a href="page2.html?param=paramvalue" target="_blank"> ..
```

The 'new window' script can access these values through

```
window.location.search
```

RE:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp

Comment: Great stuff @nimo23. Vivek's answer is worth a look too, accessing the values through window.opener

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.opener` to get variables from the page you are redirected from. Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    window.opener.yourAttributesFromSiteA;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you can use url parameters to send data from one page to another and capture it using javascript:

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");

    var params = {}, tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var qs = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
    alert(qs.attribute1);
}
```

and your js in site A:

```
window.open("B.html?attribute1=somevalue","...",...);
```